# How to count minimum number of intervals to be deleted from a set of intervals such as to break it into two partitions?

Tags: algorithms

For Eg:
For Intervals [1,3] ,[2,5],[5,9] they initially are in one common set as [1,3] overlaps with [2,5] and [5,9] overlaps with [2,5]
it can be broken to two sets [1,3] and [5,9] after removing [2,5].
Also another example
[1,24],[2,4] [3,7] [6,8] [8,12] they initially belong to one set 
but after removing [1,24] and [3,7]
we can generate two partitions ([2,4]) and ([6,8],[8,12])
how can I find minimum number of deletions? required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a graph. The sets are the vertices. Two vertices are adjacent if their intersection is nonempty. You are looking to remove the minimum number of vertices such that you wind up with at least two components. This is known as vertex connectivity.

According to Wikipedia:

"The vertex-connectivity of an input graph $G$ can be computed in polynomial time in the following way: consider all possible pairs ${\displaystyle (s,t)}$ of nonadjacent nodes to disconnect, using Menger's theorem to justify that the minimal-size separator for ${\displaystyle (s,t)}$ is the number of pairwise vertex-independent paths between them, encode the input by doubling each vertex as an edge to reduce to a computation of the number of pairwise edge-independent paths, and compute the maximum number of such paths by computing the maximum flow in the graph between ${\displaystyle s}$ and ${\displaystyle t}$ with capacity 1 to each edge, noting that a flow of ${\displaystyle k}$ in this graph corresponds, by the integral flow theorem, to  ${\displaystyle k}$ pairwise edge-independent paths from ${\displaystyle s}$ to ${\displaystyle t}$."

[K-Connected Graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-vertex-connected_graph)